# How to locate code line through memory address on Xcode console

Tags: ios

When I debug a project or when a project broke down, the Xcode console often put out some information about objects' memory address.Is there any way to figure out which instance the address is referring to and to locate related code lines?

Comment: In most cases, Xcode should display the source file and line which triggered  the error. If it doesn't, add an Exception breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks.i will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

Add a break point for all exceptions. That should do what you might really want in most cases:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering me.I'll try this way.